# Excel Export max num of rows to txt file and repeat

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

It's just one column and each column contains 11 characters, no line breaks.
I found multiple codes on how to export to txt but I can't find how to limit the total amount of rows to 500 and start with a new text file. Can anyone help?

So to be clear. I want to export 500 rows to txt. Then the next 500 to new text file.
All empty lines are already deleted and made sure every line contains exactly 11 characters.

```
Sub saveText2()
    Dim filename As String, lineText As String
    Dim myrng As Range, i, j

    filename = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\textfile-" & Format(Now, "ddmmyy-hhmmss") & ".txt"

    Open filename For Output As #1

    Set myrng = Range("data")

    For i = 1 To myrng.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To myrng.Columns.Count
            lineText = IIf(j = 1, "", lineText & ",") & myrng.Cells(i, j)
        Next j
        Print #1, lineText
    Next i

    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: put an outer loop that goes from `j = 1 to Myrng.rows.count Step 500` and the current loop inside the outer go from `i = j to j +500`.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code

```
Sub setRangToCsv()
    Dim R As Long, c As Integer
    Dim filename As String, i As Long

    R = Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    c = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    For i = 1 To R Step 500
        filename = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\textfile-" & Format(Now, "ddmmyy-hhmmss") & "_" & Format(i, "0000") & ".txt"
        TransToCSV filename, Range("a" & i).Resize(500, c)
    Next i

End Sub

Sub TransToCSV(myfile As String, rng As Range)

    Dim vDB, vR() As String, vTxt()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, j As Integer
    Dim objStream
    Dim strFile As String

    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    vDB = rng
    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        n = n + 1
        ReDim vR(1 To UBound(vDB, 2))
        For j = 1 To UBound(vDB, 2)
            vR(j) = vDB(i, j)
        Next j
        ReDim Preserve vTxt(1 To n)
        vTxt(n) = Join(vR, ",")
    Next i
    strtxt = Join(vTxt, vbCrLf)
    With objStream
        '.Charset = "utf-8"
        .Open
        .WriteText strtxt
        .SaveToFile myfile, 2
        .Close
    End With
    Set objStream = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: @JStrorma: Glad to help you!